# calculate an SVG filter at the source image resolution

Tags: svg, svg-filters

It appears that svg filters are calculated at the resolution of the final rendered space (in my case a 256px square image). I am trying to find a way to execute a filter at the source image resolution which is 512px.

Specifically I wish to dilate the image with the following filter element:
`<feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="2" />`

The end result should be that pixel will expand into its surrounding pixels giving the effect of thicker lines.

However, the source image has single pixel width lines, which do not render at lower resolutions. Following is the original image.

[image: Text]

I wish to decrease the image size, and not lose any of the rendered lines

Is it possible to force the svg dilate filter to execute on the 512px image then decrease the image size to 256 such that no lines are lost.
(note I need to use image quality pixelated so that there is no antialiasing in the image)

[A codepen that demonstrates the missing lines can be found here](https://codepen.io/jgbgy/pen/ZEQOZBg?editors=1000)

Comment: Why not just make the source lines thicker?

Comment: Can't repro, or understand the issue: all lines are always visible here. Note that your page renders completely different between Chrome and FF (I guess because Chrome has issues with SVG2's nested <svg>)

Comment: Works fine on Chrome/Mac - is this a Windows issue? Or is your screen resolution set at a low res? But anyway, you could solve this by applying the filter at the original resolution and then using a transform/scale on a wrapper <g tag to shrink it to the desired size.